# Prevent svg from sliding off video player

Tags: css, svg

When the YouTube video gets smaller, the svg starts sliding off it.

How do I prevent that from happening?

https://jsfiddle.net/48ontv29/

After you click on a play image, close the window smaller to see the home svg start sliding off it.

How do I keep the svg stuck to the YouTube video?

How it works is, after clicking the play svg it opens up where the svg on the YouTube player is visible.

When the YouTube Video gets smaller, the svg starts sliding off it.

How do I prevent that?

It starts out as this.

[image]

When the video gets smaller, this happens.

[image]

How do I prevent that from occurring?

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function showCovers(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);

  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    hideAll(config.containers);
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCovers(cover);
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function addEventHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init,
    show
  };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const players = [];

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
  }


  function addPlayer(video, settings, videoIds = video.dataset.id) {
    const videoId = !Array.isArray(videoIds) && videoIds;
    const playlist = Array.isArray(videoIds) && videoIds.join();
    const defaults = {
      playerOptions: {
        events: {
          "onReady": onPlayerReady
        },
        height: 360,
        host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
        playerVars: {
          playlist: playlist || undefined
        },
        videoId,
        width: 640
      }
    };

    const defaultOptions = defaults.playerOptions;
    const defaultVars = defaultOptions.playerVars;
    const playerVars = settings.playerVars;
    const playerOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, settings);
    playerOptions.playerVars = Object.assign({}, defaultVars, playerVars);
    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    players.push(player);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
  const defaults = {
    playerOptions: {
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
        controls: 0,
        disablekb: 1,
        enablejsapi: 1,
        fs: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        rel: 0
      }
    }
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function createPlayerOptions(settings) {
    const defaultOptions = defaults.playerOptions;
    const playerOptions = defaultOptions.playerVars;
    const playerVars = Object.assign({}, playerOptions, settings);
    playerOptions.playerVars = playerVars;
    return playerOptions;
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, settings = {}, videoIds = "") {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    if (!videoIds) {
      videoIds = video.dataset.id;
    }
    const playerOptions = createPlayerOptions(settings);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, playerOptions, videoIds);
  }

  function createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoIds) {
    return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
      show(wrapper);
      const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerSettings, videoIds);
      wrapper.player = player;
    };
  }

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerSettings, videoIds) {
    const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoIds);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
  }


  function addPlayerRandomVideo(coverSelector, playerSettings, videoIds) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * videoIds.length);
    const videoId = videoIds[index];
    const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoId);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
  }

  function init(playerOptions) {
    Object.assign(defaults.playerOptions, playerOptions);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer,
    addRandom: addPlayerRandomVideo,
    init
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  managePlayer.init({
    playerVars: {
      controls: 1,
      fs: 0
    }
  });
  managePlayer.addRandom(".playa", {
    start: 45
  }, [
    "0dgNc5S8cLI",
    "mnfmQe8Mv1g",
    "-Xgi_way56U",
    "CHahce95B1g"
  ]);
  managePlayer.add(".playb", {}, [
    "0dgNc5S8cLI",
    "mnfmQe8Mv1g",
    "-Xgi_way56U",
    "CHahce95B1g"
  ]);
  managePlayer.add(".playc", {
    start: 45
  });
  manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
    linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
    linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
    linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),
    linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
    linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),
    linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),
    linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),
    linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),
    linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),
    linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),
    linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),
    linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),
    linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),
    linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),
    linear-gradient(teal, teal);
}
/* when container is active hide the svg */
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}
/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}
.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}
.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.playa,
.playb,
.playc {
  margin: auto 20px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.playa {
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playb {
  fill: blue;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playc {
  fill: orange;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

svg.thePlay {
 pointer-events: none;
}

.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
 fill: green;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
}
.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px); /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/26/1920/1080");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/27/1920/1080");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playa thePlay" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" pointer-events="none">
      <g id="play">
        <title>Play</title>
        <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
        <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
          M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
      </g>
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame"></div>
          <svg class="home" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="green">
            <g id="home">
              <title>Home</title>
              <path d="M3 10.25V20C3 20.5523 3.44771 21 4 21H8.42857C8.98086 21 9.42857 20.5523 9.42857 20V13.2857H14.5714V20C14.5714 20.5523 15.0191 21 15.5714 21H20C20.5523 21 21 20.5523 21 20V10.25C21 9.93524 20.8518 9.63885 20.6 9.45L12 3L3.4 9.45C3.14819 9.63885 3 9.93524 3 10.25Z" stroke="red" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playb thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame"></div>
          <svg class="home" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <use href="#home" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playc thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="qe5WF4qCSkQ"></div>
          <svg class="home" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <use href="#home" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case it's much better to use percentages, in the `.home` css style change the `top: 200px` to `top: calc(60% - 25px)`.

```css
.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(60% - 25px); /*25px is half the height of the svg*/
  left: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
 fill: green;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

What does `calc()` do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()